# Timeout Exception execution in WCF due to stored procedure in SQL Server is around 4 mintues

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which takes about 4 to 5 minutes to execute.

I use WCF to connect to SQL Server. But due to the longer execution time, a timeout exception occurs.

In my client I was able to change based on receivetimeout but how do I change the connection timeout in WCF???

Comment: IT can easily be done via configuration of time out settings.
But Better to also Improve your database query.
Can you show us your query with bit of detail?

Comment: Are you talking about the **connection timeout** (time it takes to connect to SQL Server), or do you really mean the **command timeout** (time it takes to execute a command on SQL Server) ...

Answer (score 3):

Change the **sendTimeout** parameter on the client and the **receiveTimeout** parameter on the server.